# I want to see who is browsing what on ClearOs with webmin

Tags: squid, webmin

I have many users connecting to the internet through ClearOS with webmin install.

Is there a way for me to see at any given moment who is browsing what?

What is the best way to do that? (e.g. squid reports, webmin web proxy or what?)

If it is sarg how would it be configured for this task?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The squid reports and web proxy reports in Webconfig are compiled on a schedule so they aren't much use for live monitoring. You can use the log viewer to look at the access log files for squid and dansguardian in the UI but that doesn't give you a 'live' view.

The most useful method I've found is to use the command prompt. Connect to your ClearOS server using PuTTY (Windows), Terminal+SSH (Mac/Linux). Then run a similar command for example to 'follow' the log files of `/var/log/dansguardian/access.log` and `/var/log/squid/access.log`:

```
tail -f /var/log/dansguardian/access.log
```

This will show you the live logging of sites accessed through the content filter. You can even filter by passing the results through 'grep':

```
tail -f /var/log/dansguardian/access.log | grep 192.168.1.134
```

This would show you the live browsing through the content filter of the user on the IP address 192.168.1.134.

For more information check: http://www.clearcenter.com/support/documentation/clearos_guides/live_monitoring_of_web_traffic_in_proxy_and_content_filter